# Where can I buy commercial SWT components?

Tags: user-interface, swt, components

I'm looking for commercial-grade SWT components such as polished charts, grids, or layout managers (similar to what's available on .Net with DevExpress [Charts](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Index/charting.xml) and [Grids](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Index/grids.xml) for instance).

Do you have some pointers to provide ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few UI products out there for SWT.  We sell an Eclipse-based application and we had to go with a Swing component for a grid and deal with the multi-threading issues because there was nothing comparable on the SWT side.